# Google Assistant's fulfillment response comes with escape character "\"

Tags: node.js, json, aws-lambda, actions-on-google

I created a simple webhook to fulfill a Google Action intent using [Actions on Google Client Library](https://github.com/actions-on-google/actions-on-google-nodejs). This webhook is hosted on an AWS Lambda function with this code:

```
'use strict';

// Import the Dialogflow module from the Actions on Google client library.
const {dialogflow} = require('actions-on-google');

// Instantiate the Dialogflow client.
const app = dialogflow({debug: true});

// Handle the Dialogflow intent named 'favorite color'.
// The intent collects a parameter named 'color'.
app.intent('favorite color', (conv, {color}) => {
    const luckyNumber = color.length;
    // Respond with the user's lucky number and end the conversation.
    conv.close('Your lucky number is ' + luckyNumber);
});

// Set the DialogflowApp object to handle the HTTPS POST request.
exports.fulfillment = app;
```

My issue is the that the response comes back to the assistant in this form:

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "body": "{\"payload\":{\"google\":{\"expectUserResponse\":false,\"richResponse\":{\"items\":[{\"simpleResponse\":{\"textToSpeech\":\"Your lucky number is 3\"}}]}}},\"fulfillmentText\":\"Your lucky number is 3\"}",
  "headers": {
    "content-type": "application/json;charset=utf-8"
  }
}
```

As you can see, the body comes with the escape letter inserted which causes the fulfillment to fail.

I tried the following:

```
JSON.stringify(conv.close('Your lucky number is ' + luckyNumber));
JSON.parse(conv.close('Your lucky number is ' + luckyNumber));
JSON.parse(conv.close('Your lucky number is ' + luckyNumber).body);
```

Nothing changed as I think I need to reach the payload part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out there's an checkbox option in AWS API Gateway called: ***Use Lambda Proxy Integration***.

When selected it returns the JSON *as is* from my code without extra formatting.

[image: Use Lambda Proxy Integration]